# ESXi config recovery

Tags: backup, vmware-esxi, vmware-esx

I have an HP Microserver running ESXi 6.5 from a USB stick. A series of power outages seems to have caused some corruption, preventing ESXi from booting (pink screen, unable to load kernel modules).

I'd like to plug the USB stick into my Linux PC and extract the config to import into a fresh install of ESXi on a new USB stick, but I'm not seeing any promising candidates for configuration files.

I was under the impression that a working ESXi install will keep the necessary configuration stored in /etc but I'm not seeing a traditional Linux-looking file system on any of the three partitions that mount when I plug in the stick.

Gparted shows two 'unknown filesystem' partitions - might those contain /etc or whatever it is I need? Would additional drivers be required to see those partitions (assuming they do contain what I need)?

Answer (score 1):

if you can see `/bootbank` you should have an archive called `/state.tgz`. That's you configuration backup.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't see that... I can only mount a 300MB partition (packages and var) and 2x 260MB partitions (bunch of driver-looking stuff, .v00 files). Gparted sees a 2.5GB unknown partition and a 100MB unknown partition so I guess /bootbank will be sitting on one of those?